# Difference between GetValue, GetConstantValue and GetRawConstantValue

Tags: c#, reflection

What is the difference between the `GetValue`, `GetConstantValue` and `GetRawConstantValue` methods on the `PropertyInfo` class? The MSDN documentation unfortunately isn't very clear on the subject.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both `GetConstantValue` and `GetRawConstantValue` are intended for use with literals (think `const` in the case of fields, but *semantically* it can apply to more than just fields) - unlike `GetValue` which would get the actual value of something at runtime, a constant value (via `GetConstantValue` or `GetRawConstantValue`) is not runtime dependent - it is direct from metadata.

So then we get to the difference between `GetConstantValue` and `GetRawConstantValue`. Basically, the latter is the more direct and primitive form. This shows mainly for `enum` members; for example - if I had an:

```
enum Foo { A = 1, B = 2 }
...
const Foo SomeValue = Foo.B;
```

then the `GetConstantValue` of `SomeValue` is `Foo.B`; however, the `GetRawConstantValue` of `SomeValue` is `2`. In particular, you can't use `GetConstantValue` if you are using a reflection-only context, as that would require *boxing* the value to a `Foo`, which you can't do when using reflection-only.

Comment: Marc your explanation covers `GetRawConstantValue` for fields what about `Properties`. Properties can't right? If am mistaken can you pls show an example with `Properties`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel well, there's a problem there, in that AFAIK C# does not include a mechanism to express properties with constant semantics. IL includes more things than any individual language does. So no: I do not believe it is possible to give an example, short of writing raw IL.