# C# Get field value by attribute (PropertyInfo)

Tags: c#, attributes

I have the following class properties:

```
[EffectAspect(Enums.Effects.Low)]
public int Wind { set; get; }

[EffectAspect(Enums.Effects.Low)]
public int Fire { set; get; }

[EffectAspect(Enums.Effects.Medium)]
public int Water  { get; set; }

[EffectAspect(Enums.Effects.Huge)]
public int Earth  { get; set; }`
```

Now, let's say I want to calculate the total Lows, Mediums and Huges.
So I wrote something like:

```
List<Enums.Effects> result = new List<Enums.Effects>();

PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
{
    object[] attrs = p.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    foreach (Object attr in attrs)
    {
        var effectAttr = attr as EffectAspect;
        if (effectAttr != null)
        {
            int amount = (int)p.GetConstantValue();
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                result.Add(effectAttr.Aspect);
            }
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

For example: if `Wind = 3`, there would be at least 3 `Enums.Effects.Low` inside the `result` list.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class EffectAspectAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Enums.EffectsAspect { get; private set; }

    public EffectAspectAttribute (Enums.EffectsAspect aspect)
    {
        this.Aspect = aspect;
    }
}
```

The problems is: `int amount = (int)p.GetConstantValue();` throws exceptions says:

> Literal value was not found.

And I couldn't find what it means.

Comment: Well why are you calling `GetConstantValue`? That "Returns a literal value associated with the property by a compiler." - there's no such value in your case. I suspect you want `p.GetValue(this, null)`.

Comment: I inspected this GetValue method, but adding these parameters looked abit wierd for me. anyway, thanks. Im still excited you actually helped me, you're my hero in this forum :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use

```
p.GetValue(this, null)
```

instead of

```
p.GetConstantValue();
```

You can refer this link thread: [Difference between GetValue, GetConstantValue and GetRawConstantValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098873/difference-between-getvalue-getconstantvalue-and-getrawconstantvalue)